# Although tables have already been installed on my pc, error appears every time when I run the code below

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pytables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.close('all')
ts=pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020',periods=1000))
ts=ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,4),index=ts.index,columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df=df.cumsum()
plt.figure()
df.plot()
plt.legend(loc='best')
df.to_hdf('foo.h5', 'df')
```

### **Error message:**

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'tables'.  Use pip or conda to install tables.

**That is the cmd command:**

C:\Users\rehim>pip install --user tables

**The result:**

Requirement already satisfied: tables in c:\users\rehim\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (3.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.3 in c:\users\rehim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from tables) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numexpr>=2.6.2 in c:\users\rehim\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from tables) (2.7.1)

Comment: Are you using Anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this issue is often updating pytables

For Anaconda distribution try:

```
conda install pytables
```

For pip try:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables
```

Comment: No, i am using jupyter lab

Comment: try pip install --upgrade tables

Comment: Updated answer with git repo for PyTables. Does that work?

Comment: can you please specify the whole code that i need to type in cmd?. Because it is in incorrect form.

Comment: What happens when you import PyTables directly (`import tables`)? If you get an error, you have an installation or configuration problem. If it works (independent of pandas), likely your problem is a compatibility issue with pandas-tables in your jupyter lab.

Comment: Interestingly , import tables solved my problem)). Thank you very much!